# How can I build a box with multiple lines of content with two anchors?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a macro \AST (or an environment, if that helps) that will let me typeset abstract syntax trees, in the following way:

\AST{A}{\AST{B}{C\comma D}\comma E\comma \AST{F}{G}}

should produce output

```
A(B(C,
    D),
  E,
  F(G))
```

In particular, the \AST nodes should align with the baseline on their left (c.f. "A(B"), while the commas and close-parens should align with the *last* baseline of the contents (c.f. "D),"), and finally the commas and close-parens should be tight against the content to the left (there's no space between the E and comma, as if it would align with the comma after the D, for instance).

For extra brownie points, commas don't *have* to break lines, if the next content can fit on the line...but I'm ok just using a "," instead of a \comma macro for that.

I've tried using both parboxes and minipages, with [t] and [b] alignment, but that gives me the wrong vertical alignment on one or both sides, and never gives me the right horizontal alignment.

I think I could do this with TikZ, using "clever" node and anchor placements, but this question seems to be only text-based, and TikZ might be overkill.

I know I can fake it using an alignat* environment with an awful lot of "columns", but then the LateX markup doesn't match the logical structure of what I'm trying to typeset very well.

So, is there a way to build a box (or boxes) that behaves like above?  Or is that just too different from the TeX box model?  The closest I've come is the following environment

```
\newlength{\astheight}
\newsavebox{\astbox}
\newenvironment{AST}[1]{%
  \emph{#1}(\settowidth{\astheight}{\hskip 0pt plus 1 fill}\begin{lrbox}{\astbox}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\astheight}%
}{)\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \settoheight{\astheight}{\astbox}%
  \fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\usebox{\astbox}}%
  \addtolength{\astheight}{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{\astheight}%
}
```

But it produces output like

```
A(|B(|C,
  |  |D,
  |  |E
  |) |)
```

(where the pipes are zero-width, 4-line-tall fboxes) which just isn't right :)  I'm clearly misunderstanding how the \hfill works in (restricted?) horizontal mode, and I'm not sure my basic premise is going to work, anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using boxes here is overkill; it would be easier to use paragraph and/or spacing parameters to achieve the effects you're after, I think. Here's a rough example (kinda cheating because it assumes there will be no lines that wrap)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\newlength\astindent
\newcommand\AST[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \addtolength\astindent{\widthof{#1(}}%
  #1(#2)%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\comma{,\\\hspace*{\astindent}}

\noindent
\AST{A}{\AST{B}{C\comma D}\comma E\comma \AST{F}{G}}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, every time you enter an `\AST`, the indent space is increased locally.

Comment: That does indeed seem simpler than trying to use boxes, thanks!  Is there a simple way to make it robust in the face of paragraph indentation?  My full scenario is,

    \item ShortText: \AST{A}{...}

and I'd like to see

    * ShortText: A(B(C,
                     D),
                   E)

where the contents of the AST indent up to the 'A'.  If I have to, I can wrap it in a minipage, but again that seems like overkill.

Comment: @BenLerner As far as I remember, this isn't really possible in TeX in general (without extra markup around things); I think the best thing you can do here is put the whole thing into a minipage.